# Ubuntu 12.04 Cannot adjust brightness on Dell Inspiron 15: the suggested solution to change the grub fails

Tags: 12.04, brightness

Dell Inspiron 15 (Inspiron 3521). The graphic card is the integrated Intel graphic card: Intel® HD Graphics
Screen is: LED Backlit Display with Truelife and HD resolution
Install Ubuntu 12.04 downloaded in Sep. 2013.
If I use the function key Fn+F4/F5, it shows the brightness bar. But there is not effect. The brightness stays the same.

I googled. 
One suggested solution to use grub: 
acpi_osi=Linux or acpi_backlight=vendor, 
You know there are many variants.
Then I restarted my laptop: after the menu, it is stuck there.
Then I can only force to turn off the laptop, and restart to choose the recover mode. Ubuntu will start. Brightness still cannot change.
I change the grub setting back. Now the laptop can start correctly.
Of course, brightness adjustment does not work.

The second suggested solution is to install xbacklight.
It cannot work.

I used 
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.8
it seems to work. But I think it adjusts not brightness, but contrast. So actually it looks not good.

Then what should I do?
Now I do not want to use the newly bought Dell laptop any more. Or I switch to Window? Oh, I like Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/) app if anything else does not work.